# REACT: TypeError: Cannot read property 'productID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, local-storage, undefined

I am getting a freaky error with a function that parses an array of objects from local storage.

**TRYING:** to get the objects from local storage and parse their `productID` and `selectedQty` property values to int.

When I log their `typeof` value i.e.

```
   console.log("parse value", typeof item.selectedQty);
```

I get `*"parse value number"`...Great!

However I still get a REACT error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'productID' of undefined

```
 46 | if (allItems && Array.isArray(allItems)) {
  47 |   for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++) {
  48 |     var item = allItems[i];
> 49 |     item.productID = parseInt(item.productID);
  50 | ^   item.selectedQty = parseInt(item.selectedQty);
  51 | 
  52 |     console.log("parse value", typeof item.productID);
```

> Stack Track up to

```
Cart.componentDidMount
src/components/cart.jsx:14
  11 | };
  12 | componentDidMount() {
  13 |   // 1. Add Items In Cart
> 14 |   var updateCartItems = this.addItemToCart();
     | ^  15 | 
  16 |   // 2. Caclulate total cart value
  17 |   var newCartValue = this.getCartValue(updateCartItems);
```

> code

```
  addItemToCart() {
    var allItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray"));
    // console.log("--->", Array.isArray(allItems), allItems);
    // allItems.map(item => JSON.parse(item));

    var updateCartItems = this.state.cartItems;

    if (allItems && Array.isArray(allItems)) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++) {
        var item = allItems[i];
        item.productID = parseInt(item.productID);
        item.selectedQty = parseInt(item.selectedQty);

        console.log("parse value", typeof item.productID);
        console.log("parse value", typeof item.selectedQty);
        updateCartItems.push(item);
      }
    }
    return updateCartItems;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // 1. Add Items In Cart
    var updateCartItems = this.addItemToCart();

    // 2. Caclulate total cart value
    var newCartValue = this.getCartValue(updateCartItems);

    this.setState({ cartValue: newCartValue, cartItems: updateCartItems });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your **for** loop code if the loop starts from **0** then need to go till **length - 1**.

**Change**

```
for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++)
```

**to**

```
for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++)
```